# -[NSURL _CFURLRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, google-places-api, jsonkit

i am using JSONKit in my program to parse google places api but my app crashes with the following error 
**-[NSURL _CFURLRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

```
     NSString* URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.632808,77.218276&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDHft2g5IDshIpXS17uOtZzkqGGgj-p1RQ"];

NSError* error = nil;
NSURLResponse* response = nil;


NSURLRequest *URLReq = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
//[request setURL:URL];
//[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
//[request setTimeoutInterval:30];

NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:URLReq returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error performing request %@", URL);
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return;
}

NSDictionary *json = [data objectFromJSONData];

NSArray *places = [json objectForKey:@"results"];


NSLog(@"Google Data: %@", places);
```

Comment: Oh my God... Please, please, can't you read in the documentation ***what objects*** methods return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting up your "`NSURLRequest`" incorrectly and should be using [`requestWithURL:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLRequest/requestWithURL:) instead.

Instead of

```
NSURLRequest *URLReq = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
```

do

```
NSURLRequest * urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: URL]];
```

Also, a quick FYI:  Objective C convention is to use lowercase letters for variables and ivars.  Use capital letters for your class names. In other words, change "`URLReq`" to "`urlReq`" and "`URL`" to "`url`" (or even better than that, something more specific like "`googlePlaceURL`").